# Automation Script to record the screen with QuickTime using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, macos, automation, javascriptcore, osascript

I'm trying to write a JavaScript Automation script for recording the screen on my Mac. I'm finding that the API is broken at the line that is `doc.close()`. QuickTime just hangs there and eventually my Script Editor fails with a timeout error.

```
var QuickTime = Application("QuickTime Player");
var doc = QuickTime.newScreenRecording();
doc.start();
delay(2);
doc.close();
```

I eventually have to quit QuickTime from the command line with the following:

`$ killall QuickTime\ Player`

Then I open QuickTime again to find my video waiting for me there. So then I decided to add the arguments the close method and now my script looks like this:

```
var QuickTime = Application("QuickTime Player");
var doc = QuickTime.newScreenRecording();
doc.start();
delay(2);
doc.close("yes",Path("/Users/myuser/Desktop/movie.mov"));
QuickTime.quit();

Result:
Error -2700: Script too silly to execute.
Error on line 5: Error: Named parameters must be passed as an object.
```

I don't see enough documentation out there to completely understand when is being asked of me here. What is the proper way to write this script that capture a screen recording and saves that document/file to my Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `close` expects each of its arguments to come with a name. The name-argument pair can be expressed as an object with the syntax below:

```
doc.close({saving: 'yes'}, {path: '/Users/myuser/Desktop/movie.mov'});
```

instead of this:

```
doc.close("yes",Path("/Users/myuser/Desktop/movie.mov"));
```

*N.B. I didn’t try this live with QuickTime. Please tell me if this doesn’t work or if I’m mistaken.*